# modify python script with astropy package

Tags: python, astropy

I have python script that takes a fit image and plots flux versus pixel.
It draws 6 lines from a chosen central point corresponding to 0, 30, 60,90, 120 and 150 degree.
Then it calculates the flux along each line.
I want to use 2 images and overlay them and plot each line for both  images individually to compare them.
i.e 0 degree of the first image plotted over the 0 degree of the second image.
The script has an astropy package for astronomy which can be downloaded online, try anaconda.

The script is as follow:

```
#CODE CREATED BY A.AVISON 20-APR-2018#

import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits

#--- FITSNAME ---#
fitsName="fix_N7027.JVLA+eMer.eq.image.fits"

#---get fits image data---#
hdulist = fits.open(fitsName)

imData=hdulist[0].data
imData[np.isnan(imData)] = -0.0005 #== set NaNs to something which is a real number
roughSigma=np.median(imData[np.where(imData>0.0)])#=== takes the median non-zero values as a pseudoRMS
levs=np.arange(5.0,55.0,10.0)*roughSigma

#=== DEFINE CeNTRAL POSTION
y_peak=1043  #in pixels
x_peak=990   #in pixels
cutLen=500.0 #in pixels
#-- Plot...
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=[12,6])
axes[0].imshow(imData,cmap='bone',origin='lower')#'gist_ncar'
axes[0].contour(imData,colors='w',linewidths=0.5,levels=levs)

#-- Extract data values along the line...
# Make a line with "num" points...
numCuts=6
angPerCuts=180.0/float(numCuts)

for ang in range(numCuts):
    x1=x_peak-float(np.floor(cutLen*np.cos(np.radians(float(ang)*angPerCuts))))
    y1=y_peak-float(np.floor(cutLen*np.sin(np.radians(float(ang)*angPerCuts))))

    x0=x_peak+float(np.floor(cutLen*np.cos(np.radians(float(ang)*angPerCuts))))
    y0=y_peak+float(np.floor(cutLen*np.sin(np.radians(float(ang)*angPerCuts))))

    num = int(cutLen)
    x, y = np.linspace(x0, x1, num), np.linspace(y0, y1, num)
    # Extract the values along the line, using cubic interpolation
    zi = 0
    zi = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(imData, np.vstack((x,y)))

    axes[0].plot(y,x, '-',linewidth=1.0,alpha=0.8,label=str(float(ang)*angPerCuts)+"degrees")
    axes[0].plot(y1,x1, 'g.',linewidth=1.0,alpha=0.05)
    axes[1].plot(zi,'-',alpha=0.8,linewidth=1.0,label=str(float(ang)*angPerCuts)+"degrees")

axes[1].set_xlim([0,cutLen])

#=== OVERLAY 1/r^x models ===#
axes[1].legend()
plt.show()
hdulist.close()
```

The plot is attached.

One person has suggested to double the code (repeat it again) and modify the axes!!!. How can I do that?.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  If your code already works but you're looking for review / ideas for improvement this isn't really the right site to ask.  However, there is codereview.stackexchange.com which is for posting *working* code and getting code review.  If you post your question over there I can look at it.  Now, if there *is* a problem please explain what you tried to do and exactly what failed.  There's no plot attached :)

Comment: I just posted my question at codereviewer.stackexchange.com. Thank you Iguananaut.

Comment: Please link to it.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/199689/python-code-modification

Comment: @Iguananaut The last paragraph reads like a feature request, not like the code already does what it should.

Comment: @Iguananaut Question on Code Review [is on hold](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/199689/52915).

Comment: They worded things very differently over there. The question here wasn't quite clear what they were asking but seemed to be more concerned about how to write the existing code better.